# Middy API, return object with jsonBodyParser middleware

Tags: javascript, middy

Right now I have to return my data like this way, with this code:

```
import middy from '@middy/core';
import httpErrorHandler from '@middy/http-error-handler';
import jsonBodyParser from '@middy/http-json-body-parser';

async function sampleFunction (event) {
  const result = await someCodeWith(event.body);
  return result;
}

export const handler = middy(sampleFunction)
  .use(jsonBodyParser())
  .use(httpErrorHandler());
```

But I'm getting an error as a response:

```
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

so I need to return the data inside this object:

```
return {
  statusCode: 200,
  body: JSON.stringify(error)
};
```

But I thought that by using middy I didn't need to create that object, and it would be already stringified and also with a statusCode inside. I don't want to set manually each statusCode for 200, 400, 500, etc. Is there a way to only `return data` with data as a javascript object?

Answer (score 1):

Middy can be used by multiple event contexts. In this case API Gateway requires the response to follow the following pattern as you described. You can add in your own middleware to transform the response before it's returned.

Something like this:

```js
// middy v2
const strigifyResponseV2 = () => {
  return {
    after: (request) => {
      request.response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(request.response)
      }
    }  
  }
}

// middy v1
const strigifyResponseV1 = () => {
  return {
    after: (handler, next) => {
      handler.response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(handler.response)
      }
      next()
    }  
  }
}

export const handler = middy(sampleFunction)
  .use(strigifyResponseV2())
  .use(jsonBodyParser())
  .use(httpErrorHandler());
```

Comment: The answer does not work for Middy v2

Answer (score 1):

This works with Middy 2:

```
const strigifyResponse = () => ({
  after: async (request) => {
    request.response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(request.response)
    }
  }
})
```

Of course, you need to use it the same way:

```
export const handler = middy(sampleFunction)
  .use(strigifyResponse())
  .use(jsonBodyParser())
  .use(httpErrorHandler());
```